# Lithium framework data type returned is always string

Tags: php, database, lithium

I have used lithium project for REST API. When I fetch the results from database the data type of values are wrong. I have also defined the scheme but not sure whats wrong. Following is mine code:

Controller:

```
 public function view() {

    $success = false;

    $model = $this->model;
    $data = $model::find('first', array(
            'conditions'=> array('id' => $this->request->id)
        )
    );



    if($data){
        $success = true;
        $data = $data->to('array');
    }

    return compact('data','success');

}
```

Model:

```
class Franchisees extends \lithium\data\Model {

    protected $_schema = array(
        'id' => 'id',
        'name' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'location' => 'string',
        'days' => 'integer',
        'status' => 'boolean'
    );

    public $validates = array(
        'name' => array(
            array('notEmpty', 'message'=>'You must include a name.')
        ),
        'email' => array(
            array('notEmpty', 'message'=>'You must include a email.'),
            array('email', 'message'=>'email is not valid.'),
            array('isUniqueEmail', 'message'=>'email is already used.')
        ),
        'password' => array(
            array('notEmpty', 'message'=>'You must include a password.')
        ),
        'location' => array(
            array('notEmpty', 'message'=>'You must include a location.')
        )
    );

}
```

Output:

```
array (size=7)
  'id' => string '20' (length=2)
  'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'test4@gmail.com' (length=15)
  'password' => string '123' (length=3)
  'location' => string 'location1' (length=9)
  'days' => string '4' (length=1)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Output above is all string values where status, days, id should not be string.

Comment: Is explicit type casting not an option for you? e.g. `$id = (int)$data['id']`

Comment: What database do you use? Do you know which version of lithium you are using? The schema should type cast for you.